# JS library to simulate Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, webkit

There are some JS library to simulate the IE in Webkit? For instance: IE8 doesn't support `border-radius` currently (maybe on IE10). So I run a JS library that check if I'm using the `border-radius` then remove it to make similar to IE vision.

It's a crazy idea, I know, but work on IE is too slow, and if I can simulate it on Webkit, will be great! I need do it to an own project too.

**Note**: I know that exists a Chrome extension to make a IE tab, but the proposal is different: I need run on Webkit, but eliminating features not supported on IE.

**Edit1**: I'm working on a Webkit based IDE to developer HTML templates. Basically I need a button that emulate the IE view version without need a IE installed too (Mac, Linux for instance). Will be interesting have a Mozilla emulator too, for instance. Basically I will generate a CSS file to each browser too. For instance: `-webkit` properties not will be included to MSIE CSS. `filter` not will be included in Webkit CSS (*but can be emulated*).

So, I'll make a copy of current HTML page before apply a JS method that will edit or delete the unsupported content, make it similar to IE. If IE8 not support `border-radius`, it'll be removed and I'll see basically an IE version of page. If Mozilla not support `-webkit-box-sizing` it will be renamed to `-moz-box-sizing` if disponible.

Comment: Sounds like the beginning of an open source project. jQuery did it with JavaScript, now maybe you can do it with CSS :)

Comment: This may demonstrate my ignorance, but doesn't IE8 just ignore border-radius? Why would you need to remove it? Consider clarifying your reasons for wanting to do this in your question, as it will give more context.

Comment: Check out the IE7.js script and Selectivizr on this url: http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/internet-explorer-in-a-web-designers-life-problems-and-solutions/ Not sure if it's what you're looking for though. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no script, and frankly I don't expect to see one any time soon as the task of re-creating the topography of IE's support for CSS in various versions of the browser would be a massive undertaking. It would further complicate things if the undocumented hacks like `_height` were supported too.

Frankly, the best way to test your site in IE8 is to use IE8+. In versions IE8 and up Microsoft introduced Browser Emulation, permitting you to fallback and emulate any number of IE versions all from a single browser - I use this daily, and it's a fantastic feature.

Within IE, open up the Developer Tools by pressing F12 and from there you can change the *Browser Mode* to IE8. No refresh will be necessary as the browser will handle that on its own. Using this method you can quickly test versions 7 through 10 (assuming you're testing from IE10) with the click of a button.

#### Disabling CSS3

If all you would like to do is disable CSS3 features, you can use the [Strip Tease](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3StripTease/) bookmarklet. It's not a fully-developed solution, so keep in mind that it won't handle things like advanced selectors, etc.

Comment: Really. But my specific case I can't use IE or Firefox, for instance. I need emulate it. I'm developing a Webkit application and I need see the result in runtime.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues You won't be able to simulate IE in WebKit, especially since "IE" doesn't mean anything. IE8, IE9, and IE10 all have drastically different support for various CSS features. I would encourage you to install the browser on your machine, or install it via a virtual machine. That, or you could try a very incomplete bookmarklet like the one I linked to above.

Comment: I was thinking about make somethings. Like: if `IE6` doesn't support `border-radius`, remove it from element. If doesn't support `opacity` converts to `filter: alpha(...)`.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues Why convert `opacity` to `filter`? You can just place both rules on the element like I've done here: http://jsfiddle.net/VcxjP/ Any browser that doesn't understand `filter` will ignore it.

Comment: Yeah, of course. But I'm making a method to create a CSS for each browser (and view in *emulation mode*). So, I can have `site-webkit.css`, `site-mozilla.css`, `site-msie6.css`, ...

Comment: @DavidRodrigues You really shouldn't do that. Just code to standards.