# JavaScript library to simulate Internet Explorer JavaScript environment?

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript, underscore.js, phantomjs

This is not a duplicate of the [JS library to simulate Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569512/js-library-to-simulate-internet-explorer) question about simulating Internet Explorer's CSS support; this is about JavaScript functions.

**Does a JavaScript library exist which can simulate an environment like Internet Explorer's, whereas JavaScript functions are concerned?**

Basically, it would remove/overwrite the functions not supported by older versions of IE (like indexOf, etc.) or at least force any call to them to be ignored somehow.

*Effectively, what I'm looking for is something almost like the opposite of [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and which theoretically could even be used to test (in non-IE browsers) that Underscore.js is doing what it's meant to do.*

*Or* is the amount of effort needed to simulate the environment so small that I can do it quickly myself? If so, how?

---

#### The use case I'm imagining:

Using this script to simulate an IE7 environment in [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/)'s WebKit browser for automated (by Jenkins) JavaScript unit-testing with Jasmine / QUnit / etc (undecided).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd advise against that, because you'd be testing how well you support this simulation then, not IE7 itself. IE7 engine is mostly compliant with standards, save for a few quirks (like bad reaction at dangling commas) and of course, missing environment from most recent standards. Most of those quirks are either in line with other browsers or cannot be easily emulated without writing complete JS engine in JS. You may want to [consult a list on ES wiki for more details](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=resources%3aresources&media=resources%3ajscriptdeviationsfromes3.pdf) (and note "FF/Opera/Safari: same" sections, where you will likely want not to account for IE's discrepancies with ES).

Your best bet would be to either use a real IE7, that, BTW, have [very good automation interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for pretty much any testing, or, at very least, more recent IE version with compatibility mode turned on.

Comment: Compliant with standards? Really? Whether it's ES3 (not to mention ES5), or the DOM (ugh), IE7 is definitely not compliant.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain "IE7, that, BTW, have very good automation interface from pretty much any testing"? What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, the question is about JS. I'm pretty sure IE is very close to be good compliance to ES3 that was current at the time OR have exactly same quirks as other browsers. Check out link I've edited in and note amount of "FF/Opera/Safari: same as IE" in it.

Comment: @AdamLynch, OLE automation. Interface to internals of many Microsoft programs that allows you to do pretty much anything user could do in it and more. In IE you even have access to DOM from outside of browser. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx or some readily available interface module for examples (like Perl's Win32::IEAutomation).

Answer (score 4):

You may be after something like this: **http://triflejs.org/** (currently in beta)

Its an IE port of [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) for running Headless UI tests.

Like phantom, it uses V8 for running javascript API executable scripts, and instead of webkit it uses the.NET [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class for instantiating a bare-bones IE engine.

IE provides an emulation environment for running earlier versions so this will run as IE7, IE8 and IE9 if you have IE9 installed.

[image]

Comment: Question is explicitly about JS and V8 is definitely not IE's JS engine.

Comment: Actually, and answer here is definately IE's JS engine, as you are emulating IE directly without a UI.